# Ionic app icon doesn't change

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, genymotion

I'm building an android app with Visual Studio 15 Community, Ionic and Apache Cordova and I would like to update the icon of my ionic app. I'm emulating the app with Genymotion but I get the same result using the build-in android emulator from VS15.

Additionally, I used a blank ionic project.

## I've already tried

- I added the source of my icon in the config file (please note that I added the density myself, it has not been generated)

  ```
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/icon.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
  ```
- Created the app logo based on this blueprint:
  http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html
- Placed the .png file in the specific folder

[image: hierarchy of my project]

- I followed the instructions from the ionic and visual studio website
  with no results.

## I didn't try

- Actually, I didn't try to execute the command to update my ressources using `$ ionic resources --icon` because I think that as soon as I build the app (pressing the play button in VS15) it does all the work for me

Maybe I'm getting something wrong here because usually this isn't a big deal.
I really appreciate all your answers, thank you for taking the time to deal with this!

Comment: Try to execute the ionic command. It's easy and work also without a build.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try, but as soon as I try to run the command, Windows tells me it can't find the command which is true because I didn't install ionic locally, VS gets all the stuff during the build. Is there a way to run the command though VS?

Comment: Going to try this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178951/how-to-run-commands-for-cordova-ionic-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned earlier by a user whos post has been deleted (why?), all I had to do was to

1. open my command line
2. go to the directory in which my project is
3. type the command `$ ionic resources`
4. That's it! Ionic does all the rest

A quick note: I didn't know that I had to install the tools (Android SDK, Apache Cordova etc.) because I thought that Visual Studio downloads them due to the first build so why installing it locally. You must install them locally, it will not work without the tools installed on your machine.

Hope I could help

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest updates. if the splash and the icon did not update. that is because the latest version of ionic creates 2 md5 files of the icon and the splash. which i guess is locking the updates.

just delete these 2 files: “`icon.png.md5`” and “`splash.png.md5`”.

then run the following command : `ionic cordova resources`

then splash and the icon should be updated.
might be helpful to someone out there cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Density is set to "xxxhdpi" density. Maybe you need to add another screen options?
Try to refresh project, too.

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately